# How to read the result value with prepare

Tags: cassandra

I am querying cassandra with pepare set as true

```
client.execute(query, [date], { prepare: true })
        .then((result) => {console.log('Row updated on the cluster');
    });
```

here I get the result with the type of the parameters , how the the value from it ;

suppose I get something like this

```
{ date: LocalDate: 2018-12-08, calls: Long: 11 }
```

the type of this comes as an object but I am not able to read it as an object and I don't want to use regex or split() to read it. Is there a way to read it directly eg:- 11 and 2018-12-08 without datatype , I am using [cassandra-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver) for node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to it this is how it worked for me

```
client.execute(query, [ date ], { prepare: true })
  .then(result => {
    result.rows.forEach(row => console.log(row["calls"].toString()));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You receive back a set of the JavaScript object that you can access as usual, with dot notation. Here is example based on [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.6/getting-started/#retrieving-data) and your code:

```
client.execute(query, [date], { prepare: true })
        .then((result) => {
           var data = result.first();
           console.log('Row updated on the cluster: date=%s calls=%s', data.date, date.calls);
    });
```

Comment: I tried this thing before this doesn't work the way I want , thanks :)